# Firebase query to get nodes with endAt method only

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Try to find nodes with `organizer` child node and values less than `2`.

**Have such a structure**

```
{
    "path":
        {
        "-KLjhOXKn0mHmGwQTHp7": {
            "organizer": 1
        },
        "-KLrelnhPmMw4klgBOmq": {
            "participant": 1
        },
        "-KLkHLRALD1RBeHZHwU0": {
            "organizer": 2
        },
        "-KLlF8fHHnlHnJctMb97": {
            "organizer": 3
        }
    }
}
```

**Query code**

```
db.ref('path')
.orderByChild('organizer')
.endAt(2)
.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

**Result:**

```
{ '-KLjhOXKn0mHmGwQTHp7': { organizer: 1 },
  '-KLrelnhPmMw4klgBOmq': { participant: 1 },
  '-KLkHLRALD1RBeHZHwU0': { organizer: 2 }}
```

The result is not as expected, there is node with `participant` child.
Why result contains node with `participant` in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Added `startAt(0)` and works **correctly**

```
db.ref('path')
.orderByChild('organizer')
.startAt(0)
.endAt(2)
.once('value', function (snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```